# why message getting re-delivered to a MDB

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0, message-driven-bean, weblogic12c

We have a MDB running on weblogic 12c with the following definition

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") })
public class NonPersistentSalesMessageBean implements MessageListener
{
}
```

**The functionality of this bean is**

1. Receives the message
2. uses session beans for all business logic (session bean in turn use entity beans(JPA2.0))
3. reply with the response message back to the destination queue

The bean is receiving duplicate messages frequently. As stated earlier there are some exceptions at the entity bean level while inserting into the database but that's not related to the reply message. The MDB is successfully posting the response back to the destination queue but after 6 or 7 seconds am seeing the same message being sent again.

Why is the message getting redelivered when the app is successfully sending the response back to the destination queue?

Can someone please tell me what are the scenarios for a message to be redelivered ?

I can check using message.getJMSRedelivered() but would like to understand why is this getting redelivered? any help or answer s will be highly appreciated.  please

Please note this is a MDB which was running fine on weblogic 10 and we upgraded to 12c when we started to have this issue. So we reverted to weblogic 10 and now its back to working fine.

Thanks...Venkat

Comment: What is the acknowledge mode that is being used?

Comment: queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
                queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
                TextMessage jmsMsg = queueSession.createTextMessage();
                jmsMsg.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", "" + 37);
                jmsMsg.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_Format", DEFAULT_MQ_MSG_FORMAT);

Comment: AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE it is. Are you sure there are no exceptions being thrown in the MessageListener?

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your reply. I have a try/catch for all the exceptions. The MDB is calling a stateless session bean (SSB) and the SSB in turn is calling entity beans. Am getting some exceptions in the entity bean but thats is handled in the SSB itself. Is it only when there is exception in the MessageListener the message will be redelivered.

Comment: Even if there is an exception and its handled , will the message be re-redelivered.

Comment: How do we ensure the MDB is without exceptions. If there is any exception and handled will that be considered as exception and message redelivered. OR in the finally block if there is any exception , will the msg be redelivered